# Notation question. How to write the set of all polynomials (over $ \mathbb{R}$) of degree at most $p$.

Tags: notation

The question is pretty much in the title.  I have been using $\mathrm{poly}_p$ but I don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Polynomial_vector_spaces) calls this $P_p$, where the capital $P$ stands for polynomial and the lower case stands for the maximum degree.  I have seen this in some textbooks as well, but it's not universal.

This object is somewhat unusual; it is a vector space, but not a ring. It seems strange to have polynomials and not multiply them.  It's basically $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$ but written with plusses and dummy variables, rather than with commas.

Comment: It's not that unusual from a linear algebra/functional analysis/operator theory point of view: It's a good example to show the relations between a linear operator (e.g. $\frac{d}{dx}$ and a matrix representing the operator. I think it's in particular instuctive because the vector space is not $\mathbb R^n$, although it's isomorphic to it. Naturally, you'd study differential operators in other vector spaces (Sobolev or Schwartz, for example), but it's a good place to start studying differential operators.

Comment: @vadim123 , is there a separate notation for the vector field with this this set?

Answer (score 6):

The usual notation that I have seen extensively used is $\mathbb{R}_p[X]$.

Comment: Thanks, what does the $X$ mean?  Is that the domain?

Comment: It's the formal variable of the polynomial (i.e., any $P\in\mathbb{R}_p[X]$ is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^p a_n X^n$, with $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $0\leq n \leq p$).

Comment: Further note: although I have seen this notation used in English as well during my studies (and in some articles), the only "Wikipedia reference" I can find is [in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exemples_d%27espaces_vectoriels#Espaces_des_polyn.C3.B4mes). See also (again in French) [these notes](http://braise.univ-rennes1.fr/donnees/ParamHTML/Alg%E8bre%20lin%E9aire/con/Espaces%20vectoriels%20de%20polyn%F4mes/cst.html).

Comment: Hi, am am going to choose the other guy's answer but I really appreciate your help.  I am only choosing his because I am an ignorant American and can't read French.  I really do appreciate it.

Comment: No worries at all :)

Comment: @Clement C. ,Is there separate notation for the vector space with this set?

Comment: As I understand it, this denotes the set of "formal" polynomials. How would one denote the set of polynomial *functions*? I realise these are essentially the same thing (isomorphic), but I want to be explicit that I'm referring to a set of functions.